# Extracting Timestamp part from a filename in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have a filename like **SID_Statistics_20191127.xlsx**.I have to extract only the timepart from the file in a shell.The timepart may be changing but the format remains the same

Comment: Remove all non digits `name="SID_Statistics_20191127.xlsx"; echo ${name//[!0-9]/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
for file in *.xlsx; do val="${file##*_}";echo "${val%.*}"; done
```

OR a non-one liner form of solution is:

```
for file in *.xlsx
do
  val="${file##*_}"
  echo "${val%.*}"
done
```

Above will traverse through all `.xslx` files and will print the timestamp.
Please refer https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html link for more details on parameter expansion as per @user1934428's comment.

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed level of explanation for above code:

```
for file in *.xlsx          ##Starting for loop which will traverse through all xlxs format files.
do
  val="${file##*_}"         ##Creating a variable val whose value will be 20191127.xlsx, what it does is, it substitutes everything till _ last occurrence with NULL.
  echo "${val%.*}"          ##Doing substitution from DOT to till end of variable val value with NULL and printing which will print timestamp as per OP need.
done                        ##Closing this specific program for loop here.
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working.Could please explain how does it work

Comment: @AnirudhS, Sure lemme add detailed level of explanation for it now, will let you know on same.

Comment: @AnirudhS, Added a detailed level of explanation in my post now, You could also refer parameter expansion too from BASH manual, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : The reference should not be to the bash manual, since the OP asked, by specifying the _shell_ tag, for a general POSIX shell solution. So the correct refererence would be the [POSIX shell command language manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). Of course your solution works in both.

Comment: @user1934428, Sure, thank you. I have added this link into my answer now, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question description, if the format of the file remains the same and only timestamp part is changing then you can try the following code:

```
for file in *.xlsx
do
a=`echo $file|cut -d"_" -f3|cut -d"." -f1`
echo "$a"
done
```

Backticks in third line of code(a=`echo $file|cut -d"_" -f3|cut -d"." -f1`) is for execution of the code written inside the back-ticks.